# Making table and it's content via JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hw  to download arr content into the table cells from left to right and  from up to down? What is wrong with my code? How to solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

```
 <button onclick="myFunction()></button>
 <table id="myTable"  border='1px'>
        <tr>
            <th>N</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>tel.</th>
            <th>email</th>
        </tr>
    </table>    


  var arr=[[1,2,3,4,'a'],[5,6,7,8,'b'],[9,10,11,12,'c']];
 function myFunction() {
    createTable();  
  }

   function createTable(){
      var i,j;
       var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
       for( i=0;    i<arr.length;   i++ ) {
           var row = table.insertRow(1);
             for( j=0,k=0; j<5, k<arr[i].length;j++, k++ ) {
             var cell = row.insertCell(0); 
               cell.innerHTML = arr[i][k];
        } 

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i am not sure about your data structure but if you get your data in the following form.

```
[ { N: 1, Name: 2, Surname: 3, Tel: 4, email: 'a' },
  { N: 5, Name: 6, Surname: 7, Tel: 8, email: 'b' },
  { N: 9, Name: 10, Surname: 11, Tel: 12, email: 'c' } ]
```

You can use the following `tableMaker` function. It will take the properties as headers (if second argument is provided as `true`) and values as corresponding cells to generate an HTML text. So here it goes as follows;

```js
var tableMaker = (o,h) => {var keys = o.length && Object.keys(o[0]),
                           rowMaker = (a,t) => a.reduce((p,c,i,a) => p + (i === a.length-1 ? "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + "></tr>"
                                                                                           : "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + ">"),"<tr>"),
                           rows = o.reduce((r,c) => r + rowMaker(keys.reduce((v,k) => v.concat(c[k]),[]),"td"),h ? rowMaker(keys,"th") : []);
                           return rows.length ? "<table>" + rows + "</table>" : "";
                          },
           arr = [[1,2,3,4,'a'],[5,6,7,8,'b'],[9,10,11,12,'c']],
      tableObj = arr.map(e => ({N: e[0], Name: e[1], Surname : e[2], Tel: e[3], email: e[4]})),
     tableHTML = tableMaker(tableObj,true);
document.write(tableHTML);
```